# Photoshop: Is it possible to adjust layers' size and position automatically?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

We all know how to align images and layers next to eachother with the help of grids in Photoshop...but what about layers on top of each other?

Let's say, I want to make a gif out of images of a sunrise against a mountain. So the mountain part in the images should not be moving (static/fixed) throughout the sequence so you can see the light from the sun shift on the mountain...exactly like "time lapse" photography.

Problem is, even though all images have the same "reference" points (aka the mountain), the images has not been taken on a tripod, so they are all very mixed in terms of x/y position and size.

So instead of me going through all images manually (resizing, rotating, aligning) is there a way to do all this by attaching an "anchor" point on each picture as a reference point for all layers to align with each other?

For example, using several reference points on every mountain top so it knows which images to tilt/rotate, resize and align with the layer below.

Answer (score 2):

Auto Align Layers is a built-in function on the edit menu. [Photoshop: Auto-Align Layers (third section of page)](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/aligning-layers.html)

Comment: Yup, also worth mentioning that this only applies to **Photoshop CC & Photoshop CS6**